# How to pass config file to exe in bat file?

Tags: batch-file, exe

I've test.exe (console application/windows application) and `test.exe.config` in the same directory on my machine.

When I open a DOS prompt, I'm able to run `test.exe %1 %2 %3`, which successfully inserts data in an MS SQL table.

The test.exe.config is compiled from app.config, which contains this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Common Instance" connectionString="data source=eeeeee;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=YYYY;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But when I run a bat file that contains this code:

`START C:\aa\test.exe %1 %2 %3`

I get this error message:

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetNewOpenConnection()
```

I put a trace on the database, and it's not even hit when I run the bat file.

It seems that when I run the bat file, it can't find the database connection.

I tried:

`START C:\aa\test.exe %1 %2 %3 "test.exe.config"`

`START C:\aa\test.exe %1 %2 %3 /config:test.exe.config`

`START C:\aa\test.exe %1 %2 %3 /config:App.config`

They all don't work. I'd appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the working directory needs to be set in the batch file. That is why it cannot find the `.config` file. Set the working directory to the folder where the application and `.config` file resides.

```
cd C:\aa
start test.exe %1 %2 %3
```